# Unable to Obfuscate Hybrid code using Proguard in MFP 7.1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing ionic application using mfp 7.1. I have to obfuscate theapplication, for that I have refer the following link,

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_pg_creating_obfus_cli.html

```
       Using the above link I have done with the following steps:

           1) In the project.properties file uncommented the line 
              proguard.config=proguard-project.txt.

           2) Created keystore file and its added in the "ant.properties" file.

           3) finally, we build the application.

               We unable to get the "mapping.txt" file in the project
               & also not able to get obfuscate code.*
```

Can any one tell me how to obfuscate it??

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Proguard obfuscation will work on native code. You mention an Ionic application. As such you should try Javascript obfuscators for your application:

- Google Closure
- Compiler YUI Compressor
- UgifyJS

More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en).

Within MFP, the options available are to perform [JS and CSS concatenation and minification](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_concatenation.html). The other options are outside of MFP and needs to be done using the respective tools.

Comment: Thanks. But i have to achieve this using mobile first

Comment: Edited the response with what is possible in MFP